# chroot using busybox

Tags: chroot, busybox

I am facing some problem which performing chroot using busybox. 
Descriptio: I create a sparse file of 1GB and then formatted it into ext3 filesystem. Then mounted that directory as a loop back device on /mnt/busybox, then created a bin directory and copied the busybox under bin and then under /mnt/busybox executed ln -s bin/busybox bin/ls. Then when I tried running

chroot /mnt/busybox bin/busybox ls
chroot: cannot run command `bin/busybox': Permission denied

even though I m in root, and when I checked the stack trace, I found that chroot("/mnt/busybox") returned 0 but execve("bin/busybox", ["bin/busybox", "ls"], [/* 24 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied) failed. What is the prob and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Try `chmod +x /mnt/busybox/bin/busybox` to make it executable.

Comment: It looks like filesystem issue. how about if you remount that filesystem rw ?